# ActiveRecord build dynamic query conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a piece of code that seems to work. I just think there may be a much better way to achieve the desired work. The problem is to build an ActiveRecord query with an unknown list of parameters.

Here is the code:

```
query_string = String.new
query_values = []
unless params[:organization][:name].blank?
  query_string << 'name = ?'
  query_values << params[:organization][:name]
end
unless params[:organization][:national_id].blank? && params[:organization][:vat_id].blank?
  raise RequestParamsException.new('National ID or Vat ID given without country') if params[:organization][:country].nil?
  country_id = Country.find_by_name(params[:organization][:country]).pluck(:id)
  unless params[:organization][:national_id].blank?
    query_string << ' OR ' unless query_string.empty?
    query_string << '(national_id = ?'
    query_values << params[:organization][:national_id]
    query_string << ' AND ' << 'country_id = ?)'
    query_values << country_id
  end
  unless params[:organization][:vat_id].blank?
    query_string << ' OR ' unless query_string.empty?
    query_string << '(vat_id = ?'
    query_values << params[:organization][:vat_id]
    query_string << ' AND ' << 'country_id = ?)'
    query_values << country_id
  end
end
known_organizations = query_string.blank? ? [] : Organization.where(query_string, query_values).uniq
```

Country is needed when a Vat or National Id are given since these are scoped in the model:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base    

#======================VALIDATIONS=========================
  validates :national_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :country_id }, :allow_blank => true
  validates :vat_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :country_id }, :allow_blank => true
  validates :country, :presence => true  
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of Arel. For example when you write:

```
posts = Post.where(author_id: 12)
```

this query isn't executed unless you start iterating on `posts` or call `posts.all`. So you can write something like this:

```
def search_posts
  posts = Post.where(active: true)
  posts = posts.where('body ilike ?', "%#{params[:query]%") unless params[:query].blank? 

  posts
end
```

This simple example shows how to achieve behavior you are looking for.

Comment: That works nicely for .where querys, but for OR and AND operators it seems to require more work since one should only add the OR operator if a where precedes it.